# Can't rename files correctly in VSCode with VSTS

Tags: tfs, version-control, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I am using the VSTS extension in VSCode. There is supposed to be an option to "Rename (VSTS)" where the extension renames the file in version control instead of locally, but the option is not visible.

Is anyone else using this and has encountered this issue?

Original name

[image]

Context menu options:

[image]

Renamed

[image]

Result in visual studio:

[image]

Comment: What's the version control system do you used to manage the code, Git or TFVC? And for VS code, it only integrate Git VCS by default. If you are using TFVC VCS, please make sure you installed it in VS code (as this document https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#quick-start).

Comment: We use Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 15.117.26714.0

I have the extension installed and it integrates really nice except this feature.

Bottom bar
https://i.imgur.com/39ZbeuK.png

SCM Provider info
https://i.imgur.com/WH5eJPp.png

Comment: Can you also show the screen shot of VS code source control Tab?

Comment: Here you go: https://imgur.com/a/toTlf

Comment: Changes in VS code version control Tab seems not related to `index.js` and `authmasterService.js`. May be you make new changes after that. If you checkin the change in VS code first, VS won’t has any problems. If you still meet the same problem after checkin, you can create a new issue in github https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/issues.

Comment: If I rename (using the default normal one/F2) index.js to test.js. The actions in version control are found below excluded changes as "index.js(delete)" and "test.js(add)". I'm guessing this is incorrect? I don't want to lose history on index.js. Image: https://imgur.com/a/en3d8 I have also created a github issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/issues/347

Comment: That make sense. Because you rename index.js to test.js, TFVC will detect index.js no longer exist, and the new file test.js is added. And you can also find there show **A** with green background colour at the right of test.js file under excluded changes, that means the test.js file is new added. After checkin the changes, you will only find test.js (not index.js) in VS.

Comment: Yeah I know, that what I don't want though since all revision history will be lost on the file.

Comment: Not actually. All the revisions for index.js still exist in changesets after you rename the file. And after that, when you change the renamed file test.js, TFVC will also keep the revisions of test.js in changesets too.

Comment: Does your Visual Studio project also have a Project File? If that's the case, vscode hasn't updated the project file and Visual Studio shows it as

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the file is being used by another program. In my case I was running the server using the root directory.